# Page slide animations showing in one device but not in another

Tags: android, android-animation

I have two identical Android devices (only kernel versions are different)

One device is showing page slide animations perfectly. But the other device is not showing any animation.

The animations are located in

/res/anim folder

Where am I wrong?

Comment: What are the devices and kernel versions?

Comment: They are Chinese devices. one that does not show animations is: 4.2.2  kernel:3.4.34 pb22@pb22-Desktop #1